# Creating a tag list in a view of multlingual nodes

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I am creating a multilingual site in English and Swedish on Drupal 7.

I have a content type called ‘News’ which has a taxonomy term field that categorises the news posts. I have the content type set up with ‘Multilingual support’ set to ‘Enabled, with field translation’.

The views at /en/news and /sv/nyheter are working to the extent that they only show news in the users language. However, I can’t work out how to create a tag list in a block that shows the taxonomy terms for the users language.  i.e. when I am at /en/news I get a block which shows only English tags, (e.g. Fundraising (4), Events (2), Membership (2)) and and when I am at /sv/nyheter I only see Swedish tags (e.g. Insamling(4), Evenemanger(2), Medlemskap(2)).

What Translation mode should I use for the taxonomy?

What settings (fields, filters, relationships, etc.) should I use in the view?

Is it possible to create a view with two paths, one of the Swedish /sv/nyheter and one for the English /en/news?

I can provide more details on how I currently have it set up if necessary, and am also up for changing how it is set up to get it working. If you can point me to examples of this working with a views export and details of how you have the taxonomy set up that would also be really handy.

Thanks!

Comment: As taxonomy are translatable, so you just need to create the same views as you created for news and use same filters.

Answer (score 0):

You should use " Translate. Different terms will be allowed for each language and they can be translated." in the vocabulary's settings.

In the view's settings, make sure that "news category" content field's "formatter" option is selected as "Link (localized)" or "plaintext (localized)".